# Convert Doc to Jpg

Tags: file, jpeg, doc

I am looking for a way to convert a DOC file to a JPG file on my website. Essentially, this is what I want to happen:

1. On the website, the customer fills out a form and attaches a DOC file and clicks submit.
2. On the backend, the DOC file will be converted into a JPG file and emailed to me (and possibly emailed to customer as well).

Note: JPG is the conversion to choice because most customers need to upload a JPG file to online print vendors for printing. Before the conversion, the DOC files are editable party templates.

What is the best way to make this happen? I see a lot of information about converting from DOC to PDF but can't seem to find anything about DOC to JPG and just wondering if this is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `oowriter` to convert to pdf and imagemagick's `convert` to convert from PDF to JPG

Answer (score 0):

You need a virtual printer that outputs JPEG and some application that will print DOC files to the virtual printer.